# is there any way to make a loop animation in blender?

Tags: animation

a short loop animation in blender 2.81 ? How to make a short animation looping, so it plays and replays the animation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Make the animation

Step 2. At the end frame, duplicate the first keyframe of your animation and move it there.

Step 3. Done!

Comment: If want to loop on frame 1 to n,  copy frame 1 keyframes to frame n+1.  If then you only want action to have frames 1 to n, then insert keyframes at frame n and remove those at n+1.